# Define @Query on base repository interface

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Is there a way to declare a @Query on a base repsitory interface so that you don't have to declare it in all repositories? The query would have different entity names in the "FROM" part of the query.

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseAction {
    @Id
    Long id;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="AKTION_EMAIL")
public class EmailAction extends BaseAction {
    private String email;
}

public interface ActionRepository<T extends BaseAction> extends JpaRepository<T, ActionPK> {
    @Query("SELECT max(seqNumber) + 1 FROM ????????????? e WHERE e.order = ?1 AND e.action = ?2")
    Long findNextSeqNumberByOrderAndAction(Order order, ActionConfiguration action);
}

public interface EmailActionRepository extends ActionRepository<EmailAction> {
    // This works, but I don't want to repeat that in all entity repositories...
    @Query("SELECT max(seqNumber) + 1 FROM EmailAction e WHERE e.order = ?1 AND e.action = ?2")
    Long findNextSeqNumberByOrderAndAction(Order order, ActionConfiguration action);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a SpEL expression in the generic query definition to refer to the unknown entity type:

```
interface ActionRepository<T extends BaseAction> extends JpaRepository<T, ActionPK> {

  @Query("SELECT max(seqNumber) + 1 FROM #{#entityName} e WHERE …")
  Long findNextSeqNumberByOrderAndAction(Order ActionConfiguration action);
}
```

Note how we use `#{#entityName}` to dynamically insert the name of the entity that re repository will be created for.